# Flutter provider for 2 way connection

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm dealing with some problem, and can't find solution.
So I have **widget A (Card)** and **widget B (ListTile)**. There are 2 usecases:

1. Type data into card -> press "Save" -> data will be saved in the DB -> *CategoriesList* widget will be updated from the beginning with new data.
2. Inside *widget B (ListTile)* there's edit button -> hit it -> *widget A (Card)* should be updated with data from selected List tile (but the whole list should not be rebuid) -> edit data -> hit save -> update list (the same as usecase 1).

Currently as you can see I'm using one `ChangeNotifierProvider<CategoriesNotifier>` on the top. Also, in both widgets there are: `Provider.of<CategoriesNotifier>(context)` In this case there's a mess with unnecessary updated widgets or not working editing etc. Definitely my approach is wrong here :(
Please, suggest me what is the correct logic and provider strategy for this situation?
Thanks!

PS: I'm using the newest flutter and the newest stable provider

[image]

Comment: The approach that led to unnecessary updates is likely the correct one. But then, you can use extra steps to filter these updates, like using `context.select` or `Selector`.

Comment: Hi, @RémiRousselet. Thanks :) Do you recommend any videos describing `context.select` or `Selector` itself (with some examples). I read the documentation but it isn't still clear for me :(

Comment: I hope you found a solution.. If not, you can watch this series, it might help you...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeAMD0lQ5jw&list=PLjr4ufdmNA4ITb0Qpyv4mzyrLpRS7MnEj